# chip Lyx 4.2 latex

Tags: lyx

I am a recent user of Lyx. In settings, I have chosen the French language, but after compiling my text, symbols Itemize (dot, dash, star, small point) all have the same shape (the dash). At each level, it is always a tiret. I have tried to add to the beginning of the document this TeX command `\noextrasfrancais` but still have the same problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: The correct way should be to add `\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}` after `\usepackage[french]{babel}`

Answer (score 1):

You should add `\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}` in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item a
\begin{itemize}
\item b
\begin{itemize}
\item c
\begin{itemize}
\item d
\end{itemize}
\item e
\end{itemize}
\item f
\end{itemize}
\item g
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to do it in LyX is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: One can add stuff to the preamble by going to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble.