# Change every first level item in document to bullet

Tags: lists, itemize

How can I have bullets for every first level item in the document ?

Putting `renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}` in the `itemize` works well but just for this itemize. I tried putting it on top of the document but it doesn't not work.

Comment: And what if you redefine the `itemize` environment by including your redefinition of `\labelitemi`?

Comment: And how can I do that (I'm still a beginner in LaTeX)

Comment: Me too, see below...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\star$}
% instead of star you find more symbols in:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/    

\begin{itemize}
\item Global setting
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
\item is global
\end{itemize}


\begin{itemize}
\item[$\oplus$] this method is more flexible
\item[$\ominus$] but you have to type more
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it, i didn't try putting the renew inside the document. Thanks !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler You're probably having `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in your document. See my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Another suggestion is to use the `enumitem` package which provides a high-level interface to deal with such tweaks instead of delving into redefining macros:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\star$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item foo
\item bar
\item foobar
   \begin{itemize}
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: meow]

We applied a global change by setting `itemize`'s behaviour at level 1 and defining its new label:

```
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=$\star$}
```

There we go. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The bullet *is* the default for first level itemized lists, unless you load the `french` option for `babel`, which changes the symbols to a dash for *every* level to conform to what's decreed by the *Imprimérie Nationale*.

If you prefer the default bullet, then issue

```
\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels}
```

in your preamble. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardItemLabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Global setting
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See also [chip Lyx 4.2 latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80559/chip-lyx-4-2-latex)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

% save definition of itemize
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\endolditemize\itemize

\renewenvironment{itemize}{%
    % code for begin
    \begin{olditemize}%
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}%
}{%
    % code for end
    \end{olditemize}%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item B
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```